# Azure hide not mine logs - see only my logs

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-python-sdk

I write in python and use `logging.info()` to print my logs.
When I enter log stream in azure functions I see many other logs among my logs.
It makes the debugging harder.

For example I have those durable function logs:
`2024-03-17T13:16:01Z   [Information]   TaskActiviyDispatcher-2618c7d-0: Delaying work item fetching because the current active work-item count (1) exceeds the configured maximum active work-item count (1) 2024-03-17T13:16:02Z   [Information]   linuxfunction1-control-00: Skipping ownership lease aquiring for linuxfunction1-control-00 2024-03-17T13:16:02Z   [Information]   linuxfunction1-control-02: Skipping ownership lease aquiring for linuxfunction1-control-02`

I don't know if they are important (can assume it is) but I want to hide them so I can concentrate on my logs.

I'm new to Azure but experienced with AWS, so if I am missing something feel free to mention.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure hide not mine logs - see only my logs

I have created the Http trigger function with runtime stack python and added `Myfilter` function to filter the unrequired logs.

The function starts by calling `configure_logging()` to set up the logging configuration.

- Customize the log filter condition in the `MyFilter` class according to specific log messages provided in the below code, logs containing the string "MY_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER" will be allowed.

**Function code:**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        # Customize this condition based on your logs format or criteria
        # In this example, we only allow logs that contain "MY_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER"
        return "MY_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER" in record.getMessage()

def configure_logging():
    # Get the root logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # Clear any existing handlers to avoid duplicate logs
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        logger.removeHandler(handler)

    # Create a new StreamHandler to output logs
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

    # Set the formatter for the handler
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # Create a filter instance
    my_filter = MyFilter()

    # Add the filter to the handler
    handler.addFilter(my_filter)

    # Add the handler to the root logger
    logger.addHandler(handler)

# Initialize logging configuration
configure_logging()

app=func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('MY_APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER: Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

**Output in local:**

[image]

The above function deployed successfully into portal and it ran successfully in portal as well. check below:

[image]

**Output in portal:**

I have observed the required information logs in log stream. check below:

[image]

- Adjust the filtering criteria in the `MyFilter` class as needed to specific requirements.